# Operational Error: An Existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (10054)

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, gramex

Am getting this Operational Error, periodically probably when the application is not active or idle for long hours. On refreshing the page it will vanish. Am using mssql pyodbc connection string ( "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect= ...") in Formhandlers and DbAuth of gramex

How Can I keep the connection alive in gramex?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSNjj.jpg)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question more? 
Where do you have this issue?
What programming language?
What are you trying to achieve?
Can you also include your screenshot here?

Answer (score 3):

Add `pool_pre_ping` and `pool_recycle` parameters.

- `pool_pre_ping` will normally emit SQL equivalent to “SELECT 1” each time a connection is checked out from the pool; if an error is raised that is detected as a “disconnect” situation, the connection will be immediately recycled. [Read more](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#pool-disconnects-pessimistic)
- `pool_recycle` prevents the pool from using a particular connection that has passed a certain age. [Read more](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle)

eg: `engine = create_engine(connection_string, encoding='utf-8', pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=3600)`

Alternatively, you can add these parameters for FormHandler in `gramex.yaml`. This is required only for the first FormHandler with the connection string.

```
kwargs:
 url: ...
 table: ...
 pool_pre_ping: True
 pool_recycle: 60
```